# Can not show "Save site as template" link again, even after i disable the "SharePoint Server Publishing"

Tags: 2013, site-template, publishing, configuration, team-sites

I have a team site collection inside SP2013. now inside the team site collection i created a new sub site of type team site also . now for the new subsite i can save the subsite as template by clicking on "Save site as template".

but i needed to access the sub site navigation, and to show the sub site navigation under "site setting" i enables the "SharePoint Server Publishing" site feature . but after enabling the site feature the "Save site as template" disappeared. now i deactivate the "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature but the "Save site as template" link is still missing. so is there a way to show the "Save site as template"  link again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When publishing features (web or site collection scoped) get activated it becomes unsupported to save your site as a template. That is exactly happened in your scenario.

If you want to use "save your site as a template" then don't activate publishing features on web or site collection level.

Comment: but if i enable both the "SharePoint server publishing" & "SharePoint publishing infrastructure" at the site collection level, then i can save my subsites as template if i do not enable the "SP server publishing" at the sub-site level ... so i can enable both publishing features at the site collection level only,, and inside my subsite i can save it as a Template...